# How do I edit a WPF DataTemplate in VS 2010 Design view?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, datatemplate, design-view

**How do I edit a WPF `DataTemplate` (or similar) in VS 2010 Design view?**

Is that even possible? I would love it if I could drag and drop template items (such as `TextBlock`s) around like I can with normal (non-template) items. Doing so makes repositioning large numbers of elements much faster and easier than going line by line with *cut/copy/paste* methods.

For example, I would like to edit the following code in the Design view. However, the only control I can select is the `ListView`. In order to make any changes to the child-objects of `ListView`, I have to move the cursor to it or type it out. It's very limiting.

**Example XAML:**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          DataContext="{Binding}"
          d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=SampleData/PeopleSampleData.xaml}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Note:** *You might say editing 3x `TextBlock`s isn't too bad, and I agree, but I've shortened the code substantially for example purposes.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Microsoft want to sell Blend too, so they will not incorporate this functionality into the VS designer.

Comment: So blend will do it... hmmm... Is there a plugin that will do it? or some kind of trick that simulates it that you know of? Edit: Ouch.. that's $600 for blend too...